# Swipe view controller with gesture

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiswipegesturerecognizer, uiviewanimationtransition

I want to create an interaction between two view controller. 
The first view controller has a button with the action to show the second view controller from the bottom to half of his height.
From there i can dismiss the second view controller, from first view controller underneath it, by using the swipe gestures slide up (full screen) and slide down (dismiss).
For example: the same interaction in Google Maps app when long pressed a point on the map. First the second view controller is shown over the map view controller than with swipe gesture you can dismiss or changed in full screen the second view controller's appearance.

Comment: Use view instead of second view controller. Display the second view with animation when user click the button in first view controller and on swipe gesture on view set view oeigin again offscreen.

Comment: I prefer to use a view controller also to handle the auto layout mode.
With a view I'm unable to display content to fit the display boundaries.